# How to split a string between digits and characters in java

Tags: java

I need to split a string that contains a series of numbers and characters. The numbers can have decimal place. It also has to take into account that the string can have or not have spaces. I need to figure out how to use the right regex.

I've tried different `.split()` configurations but it does not work the way I want it to work.

```java
static int getBytes (String text) {

    //the string is split into two parts the digit and the icon
    String[] parts = text.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
    double num = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
    String icon = parts[1];

    // checks if the user enters a valid input
    if(parts.length > 2 || icon.length() > 3) {
        System.err.println("error: enter the correct format");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
 if i have a string text = "123.45kb"; i expect = "123.45", "kb"
 or text = "242.24 mg"; i expect = "242.24", "mg"
 or text = "234    b" i expect = "234", "b"
```

Comment: try searching https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2345/simplify-splitting-a-string-into-alpha-and-numeric-parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the logic in your current lookarounds is that `\\D` matches *any* non digit character.  This does include letters (such as `kb`), but it also includes things like `.`, and any other non digit character.  Try splitting between numbers and letters only:

```
String text = "123.45 kb";
String[] parts = text.split("(?<=[A-Za-z])\\s*(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)\\s*(?=[A-Za-z])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

This prints:

```
[123.45, kb]
```

Comment: try using `replace` to get rid of the spaces first - unless there is some need?

Comment: @stanleypena I updated my answer to handle this new edge case.